# How do I install Ruby on a server through VPN?

Tags: ruby, apache, centos, dashing

So, I'm doing sort of a challenge where I need to present a dashboard that shows real-time data about an array of things.

Decided to use dashing gem for ruby (dashing.io), I've managed to do it on my Windows PC, i've learned the basics about it and can successfully build a dashboard.

I've been given access to 2 servers on a datacenter, which I can access through VPN client, which has what I believe to be a fresh install of apache 2 on centOS.

How do I proceed on installing ruby on one of those servers to use it later as the webpage for the dashboard?

I'm really a total beginner at this but I need to do it!

Comment: Compile Ruby, or install using yum.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, even though you access through a VPN you haven't actually told us the means of access. 
But since you're on a Windows PC I assume you're either using Putty or some sort of remote desktop connection - with which you should open a terminal.

On CentOS you can do "yum install ruby" (use sudo if you get permissions denied). But last time I used CentOS it's repos were very old and ruby there was very outdated, so I recommend installing rvm https://rvm.io/rvm/install and then installing ruby through it (check the rubies installation page)

You can also go through the compile route, I've wrote a guide on it, actually targeting fresh CentOS machines, but it's 4 years old and for Ruby 1.9.3, you'll probably be able to follow the same instructions but changing the version to 2.x - ***probably***: http://techblogthing.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/complete-guide-to-install-ruby-193-on.html

Answer (score 0):

The dashing gem documentation assumes you have a few things setup in your enviroment already but on CentOS you also need the ruby development package and a couple other things. It can be a nightmare to get RVM setup on CentOS or RHEL especially if your new.

> Non-RVM Method

**CentOS**

```
yum install ruby
yum install ruby-devel
```

You will also need a JS runtime via nodejs

```
yum install curl
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
yum -y install nodejs
```

From there the rest of the steps are:

```
gem install dashing
gem install bundle
dashing new sweet_dashboard_project
cd sweet_dashboard_project
bundle
dashing start -p 80
```

**Ubuntu/Debian**

```
apt-get install ruby
apt-get install ruby-dev
```